# Why does `zsh` insert a `~` when I press the delete key?

Tags: command-line, vim, zsh

I have set my `zsh` to use `vim` style for editing command lines.

However, when I use the `Delete` key, it inserts a `~` character.

Have I misconfigured my `zsh`?

How do I turn this off?

Do I need to go back to a different command editing mode for `zsh`?

I'm a bit new to `zsh`, and perhaps answers to this question could help other newcomers with the initial configuration.

Comment: // , OH. I have been on this forum for years, and I only now just realized that.  How do I move this question to unix.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com? I use stackoverflow.com more.

Comment: @AidanEdwards This "section" is not just for Windows.  We are inclusive to all *desktop* operating systems, Linux, MacOS and Plan9 included.

Comment: If you use StackOverflow with any regularity you'd know that this would get shot down quicker than you could say "Hey, why all the downvotes..." You might want to have a look at their [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page and compare it to [ours](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and the same on [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 29):

Answering because this was the first DDG result in searching for the same issue.

**First, you need to get the code for the delete key.**

Go to your shell prompt, for example:

```
alec@su:~$
```

Execute the 'cat' program, which you will use to determine which code corresponds to your 'delete' key.

```
alec@su:~$ cat
```

Press 'delete' on your keyboard and cat will display the corresponding code.

```
alec@su:~$ cat
^[[3~
```

*You may need to press 'enter' to display the code. I did not.*

Finally, press 'Ctrl+C' to send a SIGTERM signal to cat (i.e. to quit the program execution)

```
alec@su:~$ cat
^[[3~^C
alec@su:~$ cat
```

**Now, you just need to configure zsh.**

For me, delete sends `^[[3~`, so I can put the following into my .zshrc file:

```
bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char
```

Restart zsh and you should be good to go! :)

Comment: // , Just... wow. I can't bring myself to do anything that hack-ey, but maybe something like this shows what the problem is?

Comment: By default (or perhaps after configuring vi-mode) your zsh doesn't know what to do when you press the 'delete' key. All it knows if that you pressed the key corresponding to something like `^[[3~`.

Comment: Any lore on why delete key is not delete-char by default in zsh?

Comment: @SLCH000 found this [archived post by Anne Baretta that explains further](https://web.archive.org/web/20010524234948/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html): `The keymapping problem can be traced back to the time when computers used punched tapes. ... The linux console emulates a vt220 terminal which has the following key-mapping: ... [Delete] --->  Delete     --->  "\e[3~"`

Comment: Also, if you'd like to avoid magic constants, you can use `$terminfo` as explained on [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zsh#Key_bindings).